# Java scanner reads \n in strings correctly, but not when scanning through files?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, newline

I'm coding a program that takes in lines from an input text file.
It is supposed to be a set of strings on a single line separated by the newline character. So, my input file looks like this:

```
0110\n011\n0111\n100001
```

However, when I go to print out each line, it comes out as one entire string, including the new line characters - '0110\n011\n0111\n100001'

This is my code - it works fine for Scanner when it's a static string, but not when it's from a file.

```
File input = new File(input.txt);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

When I change the scanner to read a String s, like Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s) for a String s = "0110\n011\n0111\n100001", it works correctly and prints out 4 lines, which means it recognizes the \n character, as such:

```
String s = "0110\n011\n0111\n100001";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

The only thing that's holding me back is that **we have to separate the input file strings by \n**. That's a requirement for our project.

Any idea why this happens? Is my text file wrong, is there a way to split it up by \n? Does Scanner read lines in files differently than just static strings? Should I just switch to BufferedReader? I can't wrap my head around this. I  read through some forums and manuals and I couldn't find anything on it. If I can do anything, or provide anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Don't post images of code, just put it directly in the question.

Comment: In the text file ``\n`` is two characters: ``\`` and `n`, not a single line-feed character, which is what `Scanner` is looking for when you call `nextLine()`. In a Java string, ``\n`` is a Java string literal escape sequence for the line-feed character, as parsed by the Java compiler. Remove the ``\n`` from the text file and simply write the 4 values on 4 lines.

Comment: @Amongalen thank you, I'm new here and appreciate the guidance!

Comment: @Andreas Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! Unfortunately, our project requires us to use \n between strings... so it seems I may just be splitting the strings up every time there is a \n.

Comment: @jarticus I'm believe you misunderstood the assignment, and they really do want line-feed characters, not ``\`` + `n` pairs, in the text file.

Comment: @Andreas word for word, it says "File lines must be delimited by newline characters.", and the example input file uploaded looks just like mine :( I think i will just have to go split the string by every "\n" and hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is a new line symbol, which when in a string is interpreted as such, but in your file you should just hit the enter key, which will make a new line for you and the scanner will read everything right.